# ios Decode part of an image

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have a big image which is too big to be loaded into memory but i am only interested in a sub set of pixels within that big image. Is it possible to decode into memory only this subset of pixels? I know that in Android there is a class in the API to do exactly this called BitmapRegionDecoder are something like that

I found CGDataProviderCreateSequential but it needs the raw pixels in the constructor...

Right now i am doing something like this :

```
UIImage* srcImage = ...;
    CFDataRef cgImgDataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(srcImage.CGImage));//After this call, all pixels are decoded into memory and the app crashes
char* imageData = (char*)CFDataGetBytePtr(cgImgDataRef);
```

Comment: The current wisdom says that the way to do this is to slice your image into tiles and lazily load only the tiles currently being displayed at the appropriate zoom level. Exactly how big is this image (in pixel dimensions)?

Comment: around 4096x3072 but the thing is that i want to load a tile of the big image directly into my open gl ES app. So i need to extract the needed pixels and call glTexImage2D(...) with my sub pixel data

Comment: Is the size of of the subimage you're extracting always the same, or does it vary? What's the range?

Comment: Not always the same but most of the time yes it is...max is around 4400x3300px...see the accepted answer below

Comment: Did the answer worked for you? can you provide sample code?

Comment: I added a bounty to this question. my real problem is in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951534/get-part-of-image-saved-on-disk-swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only possible way this might work is if you create an `CGImageSourceCreateWithData()` (or URL whatever), then create a `CGImageRef` using `CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider` or `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`. With that `CGImageRef`, you could TRY to use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` and pull a subsection of the big image out.

If what you are trying to do is tile the image please clarify your question as I would have more information for you then.

Comment: wow its actually working! I was previously loading the jpeg data using [UIImage imageNamed...]. It seems that the CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider + CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() only decodes the needed part. Before it was always crashing due to low memory now it works. I will check the documentation to see if there is further explanation on those methods. For your info, the goal is to load the big image from disk and send it to opengl. I need to tile it depending on the max opengl texture size supported on the device

Comment: For really huge JPEGs you can use libjpeg-turbo, and open source freely available library that uses NEON for armv7 acceleration. I use it in my PhotoScrollerNetwork project to tile and show 18000x18000 NASA images on the phone!

Comment: ok i will look into it...but isnt it software decoding only? I thought i had to use ios SDK for the built-in jpeg hardware decoder

Comment: Well, you don't HAVE to look into it - you can use the features above in my answer, if the performance is sufficient for you. For truly massive images you will have to use an open source libjpeg library, as apple does not offer one on iOS (or the Mac either). Learning to use these libraries is a long complex process so if you can live with Quartz your life will be easier!

Comment: Yes of course :) It was just because i am curious, it seems pretty cool. Thx!