# Get part of image saved on disk (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3

A very large image saved at DocumentDirectory. This image is asked to be display at the image view depending on users current window that can change by zooming and dragging.

> I can't load the Image at memory with it full size and then start
>   cropping. This is so costy.

**The following code gets resized(smaller,scaled) copy of the image saved on disk:**

```
if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL, nil) {

    let maxSize = max(thumbSize.width, thumbSize.height) / 2.0

    let options = [
                kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxSize,
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true
    ]

    let scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options))

}
```

What I need is to get part of the image directly from disk given s specfic window rect(x, y, width, height).

**How I can achieve that?**

Comment: Any ideas?!!!!!!!

Comment: You may be interested by `seekToFileOffset:` and `readDataOfLength:` methods of `NSFileHandle` that can make you read only a part of the big image file. But you may have then to manage to recreate an UIImage from the part of that file (maybe by adding some header/endOfFile to it in order to make it a "PNG/JPEG" look alike).